Get the list of blobs that match the metadata key and value from Azure Storage blob using C#
I have different folder in a blob container in Azure storage blob.
I have structure as
ContainerName/ParentFolder/Subfolder1/Blob
ContainerName/ParentFolder/Subfolder2/Blob
ContainerName/ParentFolder/Subfolder3/Blob

In each folder, I have a blob with meta data key as "Account" and its value as "Test1".
I am trying to get the list of blob details irrespective of the folder based on meta data key and value using the code shown here, but it's not returning results.
Am I doing anything wrong in the code?
private IOrderedEnumerable<CloudBlockBlob> GetListOfBlobs(string blobConnString)
{
     var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnString);
     var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

     var blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName");
     var blobList = blobContainer.ListBlobs("ParentFolder");

     var matchBlobs = blobList.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
                              .Where(r => r.Metadata.Any(r => r.Key == "Account" && r.Value == "Test1"))
                              .ToList()
                              .OrderBy(d => d.Properties.Created);

     return matchBlobs;
}


Why can't try with new package Azure.storage.blobs?

Check the below answer.


Get the list of blobs that match the metadata key and value from azure storage blob using c#.

You can use the below code which list the blobs that match the metadata key and value using Azure.Storage.Blobs package.
In my environment the same folder structure:
test/(container)
   foo/(parent folder)
     bar/with blobs(subfolder) 
     demo/with blobs(subfolder)
     test/with blobs(subfolder)

Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace BlobMetadataExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string blobConnectionString = "xxx";
            string containerName = "test";
            string folderPath = "foo"; // Specify the folder path prefix
            string metadataKey = "Account"; 
            string metadataValue = "Test1"; /

            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobConnectionString, containerName);

            var blobs = await GetBlobsByMetadataAsync(blobContainerClient, folderPath, metadataKey, metadataValue);

            Console.WriteLine("Blobs with specified metadata:");
            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Blob Name: {blob.Name}, Created On: {blob.Properties.CreatedOn}");
            }
        }
        public static async Task<IOrderedEnumerable<BlobItem>> GetBlobsByMetadataAsync(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, string folderPath, string metadataKey, string metadataValue)
        {
            var matchingBlobs = new List<BlobItem>();
            await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: folderPath, traits: BlobTraits.Metadata))
            {
                if (blobItem.Metadata.TryGetValue(metadataKey, out var value) && value == metadataValue)
                {
                    matchingBlobs.Add(blobItem);
                }
            }

            return matchingBlobs.OrderBy(blob => blob.Properties.CreatedOn);
        }
    }
}

Output:
Blobs with specified metadata:
Blob Name: foo/bar/industry.csv, Created On: 06-11-xxx 07:49:24 +00:00
Blob Name: foo/bar/sample5000.xlsx, Created On: 06-11-xxxx 10:05:26 +00:00
Blob Name: foo/demo/cert_2.key, Created On: 13-11-x 03:5xxxx 5:56 +00:00
Blob Name: foo/test/Octkb2 24.md, Created On: 13-11-xxxx 03:56:19 +00:00



Thanks for the reply . I understand we can loop through the folder to get the metadata and list . Is there a way we can get the list with out for loop each blob to get the data
I have lot of data in each folder so trying to figure out if there is a way to get list and avoid for loop

Will check into this.
